# How give random value for Template variable?

Tags: c++, templates, matrix, types

I am building a matrix class , which lets the user specify what the type of the data will be. ie using a template. I want to be able to assign random values to each position in the matrix based on the template.

if the template is double , I want a double random value , and if it is int , I want an int random value. Is there some way to do it ?

Code :

```
template <class T>
void matrix<T>::randFill(T start , T end ){
    std::srand(time(0));
    for(size_t i = 1; i <= _rows ;i++){
    for(size_t j = 1; j <= _cols l i++){
         _matrix[(i-1)*_cols + (j-1)] = static_cast<T>(std::rand % (end - start)  + 1)
       }
     }
}
```

My question really is how can I know what the template T will be at runtime and change result accordingly? Is there some way to do something like a switch statement which matches the type of the template with certain predefined types and gives the appropriate values ? That is a naive way to put this, but is there some feature in C++ to do this ? I know about the typeid operator, but I couldn't figure out how to do it. Could you give me a heuristic to do this? Just point me in the right direction , I will do the rest.

On a side Note. In the future I want my matrix class to be able to take a struct of 3 int s so that I can represent an RGB image. Is there some way to extract  all the available data members in an arbitrary struct or class ,and assign a random value to it ?

Sorry for being verbose , I wanted to give a clear idea of what I want to do. 
-Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call a function overloaded on each type:

```
for(size_t i = 1; i <= _rows ;i++){
    for(size_t j = 1; j <= _cols l i++){
        set_random(_matrix[(i-1)*_cols + (j-1)]);
   }
}
```

With:

```
void set_random(int& val) { val = ... }
void set_random(double& val) { val = ... }
void set_random(char& val) { val = ... }
// etc.
```

Comment: make the compiler do the work for us. That is great. Do you have any pointers for my side Node. ie. get all data members in an arbitrary struct or class and assign values to them ?

Comment: @nnrales C++ doesn't have reflection, so there's no automated way to do such a thing.

Comment: Okay. I didn't know about reflection so I will look it up. thanks for the help !.

Comment: If you don't mind , could you give me an example of a language that supports reflection ?